# Groovy (SoapUI) choose which request are compatible with deployed API and use them

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to write SoapUI test cases, which can be run on different versions of API. Before running test case, it needs to find which API versions are deployed. And then choose which request can run on those API versions. API versions are changed every day, so we need that SoapUI test cases can handle different versions.

I wrote simple script in Groovy, which checks deployed API version (major version) on servers and save them in the test suite properties. Also this script checks If we have requests for those versions. It fails when we don't have request for deployed version.

*Test Suite Properties looks something like this:*

[image: CustomProperties]

**I also have prepared requests for different versions. But now I need to make a Groovy script which will choose appropriate requests. Any idea which is easiest way to do that?**

My idea was to make map (apiRequests) with API names as 'keys' and requests names as 'values'. Than use .each and every loop it will get version of that API from Test Suite Properties. I have made this:

**API:** onboarding, communication, customer-bill, etc.

**Requests:** Login, Logout, List of inbox messages, See bill history, Retrieve unpaid bills, etc.

```
def apiRequests=[
  'onboarding' : ['Login', 'Logout'],
  'customer-bill' : ['See bill history', 'Retrieve unpaid bills'],
  'communication' : ['List of inbox messages'],
]
apiRequests.each{k,v-> 
def apiVersion =  testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Independent functions").getTestCaseByName("Get API Version").getPropertyValue("$k")
log.info apiVersion     //returns version for api in that loop (e.g. '2' for onboarding api)

}
```

And now I need to build complete request name (e.g. 'Login - v2'). I think that I can use something like this:

```
def finalRequest = (v + " -v " + apiVersion)
```

But this doesn't work because I have more 'values' for one 'key'.

And then I need to disable other requests (different than all finalRequests) ->

1. Loop - **disable:** 'Login - v1', 'Login - v3', 'Logout - v1', Logout - v3'; **enable:** 'Login - v2', 'Logout - v2'
2. Loop - **disable:** 'See bill history - v2; **enable:** 'See bill history - v1'
3. Loop - etc.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I would like to make this groovy script universal for every test case. So it will run loop for every request stored in 'apiRequests' and If they exist in actual test case, then it choose them and disable others.

Answer (score 0):

This would work what are your looking for -

**PS:** I assume the properties are added on `Project` label scope. If you add the properties `TestSuite/TestCase` lable, change the `context.expand('${#TestSuite/TestCase#....}')`  accordingly.

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps.each { k, v ->    
  if(k.inspect().contains(context.expand('${#Project#onboarding}'))) { 
     log.info k
     v.setDisabled(true)       
   }
  if(k.inspect().contains(context.expand('${#Project#communication}'))) { 
    log.info k  
    v.setDisabled(true)
  }
  if(k.inspect().contains(context.expand('${#Project#customer-bill}'))) { 
    log.info k  
    v.setDisabled(true)     
 }
}
return
```

PS: 
I would suggest to change the value of your property with adding `v` as version before the version number like you named your `testStep` name - `Login - v1` , `Login - v2` etc. 
So the property would look like -

```
|Name          | Value |
|----------------------|
|onboarding    |  v2   |
|communication |  v3   |
|customer-bill |  v1   |
```

At any case the above code ll work.